# Yubikey 4 not working (Linux & Windows)

Tags: linux, windows-10, smartcard, u2f, yubikey

I received a Yubikey 4 a few days ago. I got it along a special WIRED Magazine offer. The problem with the key is, that it is not recognized neither by Windows 10, nor by Linux (Mint 18).

**Linux**

When I execute `sudo lsusb -d 058b:004c -v`, the key is shown as

```
Bus 006 Device 009: ID 058b:004c Infineon Technologies 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x058b Infineon Technologies
  idProduct          0x004c 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Infineon AG
  iProduct                2 SLE78 USB Solid Flash(TM) Kit
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           86
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               20mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        11 Chip/SmartCard
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              4 USB Smartcard
      ChipCard Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                54
        bDescriptorType        33
        bcdCCID              1.10  (Warning: Only accurate for version 1.0)
        nMaxSlotIndex           0
        bVoltageSupport         1  5.0V 
        dwProtocols             2  T=1
        dwDefaultClock       3580
        dwMaxiumumClock      3580
        bNumClockSupported      0
        dwDataRate           9600 bps
        dwMaxDataRate        9600 bps
        bNumDataRatesSupp.      0
        dwMaxIFSD             254
        dwSyncProtocols  00000000 
        dwMechanical     00000000 
        dwFeatures       00020840
          Auto parameter negotation made by CCID
          Short APDU level exchange
        dwMaxCCIDMsgLen       263
        bClassGetResponse    echo
        bClassEnvelope       echo
        wlcdLayout           none
        bPINSupport             0 
        bMaxCCIDBusySlots       1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I digged a bit around ([USB ID database](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)) and in my opinion this Vendor/Product ID combination looks really wired (not as the magazine). Since 058c is the Vendor ID of Infineon Technologies (Yubikey has 1050), the Product ID 004c makes no sense.

SmartCard and Yubicon Linux tools (ykinfo, ykman, opensc-explorer, opensc-tool,...) did not recognize the key.

```
bash$ sudo ykinfo -v
Yubikey core error: no yubikey present
```

Also the following instructions were useless:
https://developers.yubico.com/libu2f-host/Mode_switch_YubiKey.html

**Windows 10**

In Windows 10, the Yubico Tools also do not seem to work, but at least, Windows System HW Information tells something about a CCID-Device.

**Further Investigation**

I already asked Yubico support which answered within a day, but the suggestions (reboot, try another USB port) did not work and I did not yet get a follow up.

Since I don't have a second one at hand, I can not eliminate the case that it is simply defect.

Maybe somebody else has some suggestions, how to further debug or fix the issue.

**Edit**

The LED of my key 
also never flashed. No life sign.

**Edit 2**

Yubico is sending me a new key. Seems a batch has been misconfigured in production.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to post this as a comment. I am actually seeing the exact same problem with the Yubikey4 that I received yesterday as part of the same Wired promotion. I tried it across 3 different machines on both OSX and Linux. The LED does not come on and it also reports as an Infineon Technologies device. I tried various tools provided by Yubi, but none of them were able to detect the device.

Comment: Daryl Robbins wants to comment " I am actually seeing the exact same problem with the Yubikey4 that I received yesterday as part of the same Wired promotion. I tried it across 3 different machines on both OSX and Linux. The LED does not come on and it also reports as an Infineon Technologies device. I tried various tools provided by Yubi, but none of them were able to detect the device."

Comment: Sounds like there might be a bad batch sent out in the promotion. This is almost certainly going to have to go back to Yubico and I hope they'll be VERY interested in scrubbing this egg off their face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an email from Yubi support, they indicated to me this is a factory configuration issue and requires a replacement.

Their email is quoted below:

> Thank you for your patience on this.
>
> We have recently discovered that a small subset of the YubiKeys that were distributed for this promotion were shipped out misconfigured, and therefore will not work. The serial number that you submitted is one of those keys. Because of that, we are providing you with a new branded YubiKey 4. Please send your preferred mailing address and we will get the replacement sent out as quickly as possible.
>
> We are very sorry for any inconvenience we have caused. Thank you for your support. If you have any further issues, please respond to this message or you can open a new support case at yubi.co/support.
>
> Sincerely,
>   James Alseth

To receive a replacement, raise a support ticket with Yubi (http://yubi.co/support) including the following information:

- Serial number of the defective device (it can be found on the back of the key)
- Shipping address for a replacement

They will be able to determine from the serial number if yours was one of the impacted units.